# I am trying to debug python code given but it gives the error as given

Tags: python

I am getting the error as

```
Traceback:
    in <module>
    in merge_ranges
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Can someone suggest what is the issue and also for debugging I am using code as

```
meets = [(1,3),(5,8),(8,14),(13,17)]
print '{} should be {}'.format(merge_ranges(meets))

def merge_ranges(meets):

    #sort by start time
    sorted_meetings = sorted(meets)

    merged_meetings = sorted_meetings[0]

    for current_meeting_start, current_meeting_end in sorted_meetings[1:]:
        last_merged_meeting_start, last_merged_meeting_end = merged_meetings[-1]

        if (current_meeting_start <= last_merged_meeting_end):
            merged_meetings[-1] = (last_merged_meeting_start, max(last_merged_meeting_end, current_meeting_end))

        else:
            merged_meetings.append((current_meeting_start, current_meeting_end))
    # write the body of your function here
    return merged_meetings
```

Answer (score 2):

You initialized variable `merged_meetings` as a single tuple, however it should be a list of tuples.

Thus, you have to modify the initialization of `merged_meetings` to

```
merged_meetings = [sorted_meetings[0]]
```

and the result of your testcase will be

```
[(1, 3), (5, 17)]
```

Comment: I tried this...but its giving error as IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: This is caused by your `print` clause, rather than the `merge_ranges` method. You give only 1 value while leaving two placeholders, i.e.`{}`, in the format string. Try `print '{} should be {}'.format(meets, merge_ranges(meets))`

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a tuple as you are in the following two lines:

```
merged_meetings[-1] = (last_merged_meeting_start, max(last_merged_meeting_end, current_meeting_end)) # here

merged_meetings.append((current_meeting_start, current_meeting_end)) # and here
```

Tuples are immutatable. Not only are you using a tuple, you are unpacking more values than you should be.

Comment: While this is correct, it has not yet occurred in the OP's code :P It will bite him/her right after s/he solves this error, so I'll upvote :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. The error you described will come first, and after that, this error will come.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
last_merged_meeting_start, last_merged_meeting_end = merged_meetings[-1]
```

`merged_meetings` is a tuple, say `(1,3)`.
`merged_meetings[-1]` is a single value, 3.

You try to unpack 3 to two variables, which is not possible.

Comment: This would be easier to spot if he would use a namedTuple.